# How to spellcheck all words in a buffer

Tags: flyspell, ispell

Is there a way to make a whole spellcheck in a buffer instead of check every word as you type using `flyspell`, like using `aspell`  command with a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `flyspell-mode`, run `flyspell-buffer`.

Answer (score 2):

There's (<kbd>M-x</kbd>) `ispell-buffer` which checks entire buffer word by word and prompts on every misspelled word.